# Convergence in probability, but not almost surely

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Independent random variables $(Y_n)_{n≥1}$ are defined by 
$$P(Y_n = n) = 1/n$$

$$P(Y_n = 1) = 1 − 1/n$$

Show that, as $n → ∞, Y_n$ converges in probability but not almost surely.

I am having trouble with this as I can derive |$Y_n -Y$|, do I not need this here? I'm sure there is a simple explanation that I cant see

Answer (score 2):

$Y_n$ converges to $1$ in probability, since for any $\varepsilon > 0$ we have
$ \mathbb{P}(\lvert{Y_n - 1}\rvert > \varepsilon) = \mathbb{P}(\lvert{n-1}\rvert > \epsilon) = \frac{1}{n} $ for $n$ large enough, hence this converges to $0$.

However, it does not convergence a.s. to $1$, which can be shown using Borel-Cantelli lemma: If $\lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n(\omega) = 1$, this means that for all $n \ge n_0$ for some $n_0$ we have $Y_n(\omega) = 1$, but we have $\limsup_n \{ Y_n = n \} = \cup_{m = 0}^\infty \cap_{n = m}^\infty \{ Y_n = n \}$ has measure $1$, as $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(\{ Y_n = n \}) = \infty$. But if $Y_n = n$ for infinitely many $n$ almost surely, then there cannot be any convergence.

Comment: The existing answer is perfect. I just wanted to add some extra info that this proof uses the "second Borel–Cantelli lemma" which depends on the independence assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $P(|Y_n-1|\geq\epsilon)\leq P(Y_n\neq1)=\frac1{n}$ and consequently $P(|Y_n-1|\geq\epsilon)\to 0$ for $\epsilon>0$.

This shows that $Y_n\to 1$ in probability.

For proving that there there is no a.s. convergence you can apply the [second Borel-Cantelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) on the events $E_n:=\{Y_n=n\}$.